# How to insert multiple rows by select or checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, select, checkbox

I've got a problem with inserting multiple row to one table.

I've got a 3 tables:
1. student with id_student
2. ankieta with id_ankieta
3. student_ankieta with id_student and id_ankieta

I want to choose students from database using select or checkbox and choose one id_ankieta. After confirming, there are rows created in table (student_ankieta).
Now I can choose students but when I confirm, only one student gets added to the database.

Can anyone help me corect the code?

```
     <?php
echo'<form method="post" action="student_ankieta.php">
        <div class="box" style="margin:0 auto; top:0px;">
            <h1>Student - ankieta:</h1>

            <label>
                <span><br/>Ankieta:</span>
            </label>
            <select class="wpis" name="id_ankieta">
                <option>wybierz ankiete</option>';
                $query = "SELECT * FROM ankieta";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                    {
                       echo '<option value="'.$row['id_ankieta'].'">' . $row{'rok_akademicki'}.' '. $row{'semestr_akademicki'}.' '.$row{'active_ankieta'} .'</option>';
                    }
            echo '
            </select>';

            $query = "SELECT * FROM student";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            echo'
            <label>
                <span><br/>Wybierz stundentów:</span>
            </label>
            <select multiple="multiple" name="id_student[]" size="10">';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                {
                    echo '<option  class="wpis" value="'.$row['id_student'].'" />'.$row{'pesel'}.' '. $row{'nazwisko'}.' '.$row{'imie'} .'</option>';
                }

            echo'<br/><input class="button" type="submit" value="Dodaj ankiete" name="dodaja">';             

            if(isset($_POST['dodaja'])) 
                {
                    $id_ankieta = $_POST['id_ankieta'];
                    if(empty($_POST['id_ankieta']))  
                        {
                            echo '<p style="margin-top:10px; font-size:75%; font-family: Calibri; color: red; text-align:center;">Musisz wypełnić wszystkie pola.</p>';
                        } 
                        else
                            {
                               $id_student = $_POST['id_student'];
                               for ($i = 0; $i < count($id_student); $i++) 
                               {
                                    $id_student = $id_student[$i];
                                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO student_ankieta (id_student, id_ankieta) VALUES ('" . $id_student . "','$id_ankieta')");
                                }
                            }
                }
  echo'</div></form>';?>
```

Comment: Clean up your code. It is a mess.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I have impoved it a little bit. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

**Put all students in to an array with the key = id_student**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ankieta";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  students[$row['id_student']] = array($row['pesel'],$row['nazwisko'],$row['imie'];
}
```

**If the form was posted the confirm will = 1 (from hidden input)**
**When first enter script "confirm will = 0**

When zero, display all student with a check box with a name which includes the id_student in the format of n-i_student.

```
if intval($_POST['confirm']) = 0){


     echo '<form action = "confirm.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="confirm" value="1"/><table>';

     foreach ($students as $id => val){
       echo "<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"n-$id\" value=\"1\" />&#x2002;Select&#x2003;</div></td>$val[0]<td>$val[0]</td><td>$val[1]</td><td>$val[2]</td></tr>";
     }

     echo '</table></form>';
}
```

**When confirm = 1**

The checkboxes that were checked are inserted.
Check each post value for a key the starts with "n-"
get the rest of the key value after the n- for the id_student value.

**Still 1 Major Problem, I do not know where to get the $id_ankieta'**
**And match it with the id_student.**
**I left that value as $val[???]**

```
elseif intval($_POST['confirm']) = 1){

  foreach ($_POST as $k =>$val){
    if (inval($val) == 1 && substr($k,0,2) == 'n-'){
     $id = substr($k,2);
     $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO student_ankieta (id_student, id_ankieta) VALUES ('$id','" . $students[$id][$val[???]] . "')");
    }
  }

}
```